E: Unable to locate package libncurses5
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am trying to build AOSP from source. I am unable as I recieve this error:
 error while loading shared 
 libraries:       
 libncurses.so.5: cannot 
 open shared object file:       
 No such file or directory    
 06:11:49 ninja failed with: 
 exit status 1

Does anyone know where i can find
libncurses5-dev
libncursesw5-dev
I can't seem to find them anywhwre on the web

The answer is exactly the same as for the above question - only the last part (since you didn't install invalid packages). ^^^

Indeed it does, sir. Many thanks.

v5 you looking for was available in 14.04 (ie. back in 2014-April release; long ago!), but had been replaced by v6 for 16.04 & later releases.. v6 was last available for 22.04, being replaced by ....    all from CLI searches
